# Why does jQuery $() take inputs as strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just starting to learn JavaScript and jQuery using CodeAcademy. From my understanding, the input for `$()` is always a string (e.g. `'div'`). I'm trying to figure out the logic behind why this is.

EDIT: I think the reason I'm confused by this is because 'div' is not the same as just div. The former is a string and the latter, I'm not sure exactly. When I think of a string, I think of a very basic string of characters that don't mean anything. Other datatypes mean something more usually. If we put in 'div' into the selector, it seems like we're putting in a string that means nothing?

**FINAL EDIT: This question is now closed but wanted to go ahead and add some context as to what happened here now that I understand the answer to my own questions. I made the mistake of jumping into jQuery before understanding JavaScript. I didn't understand that $() was short for utilizing jQuery how the Document Object Model (DOM) worked.**

**Lesson: CodeAcademy is great to get you started without knowing what exactly you're doing but please take a real course on JavaScript before learning jQuery!**

Comment: It's the selector to tell jQuery what object or element you are selecting.

Comment: Good time to learn how to read API docs ... in other words, your answer is in the manual. Also not true that `$()` only accepts  string

Comment: Added some additional details.

Comment: The short answer is that in `$(div)` the `div` (without quotes) would be a token, and jQuery, being a JavaScript library, can't add new tokens to the language, so it has to parse the selector from a string. This is a rather fundamental distinction which should become clear over time when you study more of JavaScript's basics.

Answer (score 2):

`$()`, or `jQuery()`, is a **function**. It accepts different parameters, amongst them: DOM objects and strings.  Please read the documentation for the [jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/).

Strings in this context are *jQuery selectors*, also used in other jQuery functions (like `appendTo` and many others). Read about [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

There is indeed a distinction between `"div"` (the string, a selector that matches all divs in a document) and `div` the DOM object: DOM objects are scripteable object instances that represent each part of the HTML as understood by the browser (with methods and properties).

jQuery function returns another type of object ([jQuery Object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)) which references one or more elements (which could be `<div>`).

Example:

```
// 'div' is a selector, a string.
// $() is the jQuery function (you can use jQuery('div').
var allDivs = $('div'); 

// allDivs now contains a jQuery object that references all div objects.
// We can chain jQuery method calls on this jQuery object selection.
allDivs.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

At its core `$()` is a Javascript function so everything that goes in between the parenthesis are considered as function *parameters*.

If you give the function a parameter `div` instead of a string `"div"` it is considered as a Javascript *variable*.